# Dereferencing an array of void pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I have an array of void pointer pointing to objects of different types and I want to pass them through a function and cast them to pointers of their respective type, how would I go about doing this? I've tried this current code, but I get error:

> ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type

```
objectA myObjectA;
objectB myObjectB;
objectC myObjectC;
objectD myObjectD;

void *data[4];

data[0] = static_cast<void *>( &myObjectA );
data[1] = static_cast<void *>( &myObjectB );
data[2] = static_cast<void *>( &myObjectC );
data[3] = static_cast<void *>( &myObjectD );

void dereference( void *data )
{
    objectA *objA_ptr = static_cast<objectA *>( data[0] );
    objectB *objB_ptr = static_cast<objectB *>( data[1] );
    objectC *objC_ptr = static_cast<objectC *>( data[2] );
    objectD *objD_ptr = static_cast<objectD *>( data[3] ); 
}
```

Anyone know the correct way to implement this?

edit: For context, I'm using opencv and trying to create a simple gui interface with a trackbar. Opencv allows for userdata to be fed into the TrackbarCallback which is called when the slider is moved, but only in the form of a void pointer.

```
 int createTrackbar( const string& trackbarname, const string& winname,
                           int* value, int count,
                           TrackbarCallback onChange=0,
                           void* userdata=0);
```

Comment: My question is; why in the world are you using `void*` at all?  This is C++, you have templates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Say I have an array of void pointer

```
void deference( void *data )
```

That's not an array of void pointers, it's a single void pointer.

Change that to `void **`, and then since you're mixing C and C++ styles up anyway, why not just use a C style cast? :

```
objectA *objA_ptr = (objectA *) data[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Derive them all from the same base class.
2. make the destructors virtual if your function needs to delete them.
3. make your array `BaseClass *data[4]`
4. make your function `void deference(BaseClass **data)`

Comment: Alternately, use a `vector<BaseClass*>` instead of an array.

Comment: @JohnBode ...and use shared_ptr instead of putting "plain" pointers in a vector

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `reinterpret_cast<>()` instead of `static_cast<>`.

Comment: If static_cast doesn't work, then obviously reinterpret_cast can only be more wrong here?

Comment: It depends what you mean with "doesn't work". <code>reinterpret_cast<></code> it the most mighty and therefore most dangerous cast. It works in the sense that it throw down all compiler type checks and assure "I know what I ask for - Do it!".

Comment: And that is good, because with `void*` compiler has no information to perform any typecheck.

Answer (score 1):

The correct function prototype needs to be

```
void dereference(void **data)
```

since you're passing an array of `void *`, and as we all know in C and C++ an array expression is replaced with a pointer expression in most circumstances.

Is there any particular reason why you must use an array of pointers to objects of differing classes?  This smells like a C solution to a C++ problem.